# PowerShell Graph required scopes complete full list

Tags: powershell, graph, azure-powershell

How and where can I get the PowerShell Graph Required Scopes list?
I need to get the list of all scopes like:

```
"Chat.ReadWrite.All",
"Directory.AccessAsUser.All", 
"Directory.ReadWrite.All", 
"Group.Read.All",
"Mail.ReadWrite",
"People.Read.All",
"Sites.Manage.All",
"Tasks.ReadWrite.All",
"User.Read.All",
"User.ReadWrite.All"
```

### Update

I have found the way to list all Read Only rules using this command:

```
Find-MgGraphPermission | ? {$_.Name -match "\bRead\b"}
```

It would be great if someone can update the official URL for the documentation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference ? Seems pretty much up-to-date to me.

Comment: That's great, and so does the *.Read and *.Read.All the same?

Comment: I looked at 2 randomly and it look like the "Read" are the delegated permissions (eg: on behalf of the currently signed-in user) and the "Read.All" are for the application permissions (eg: App. can read everything from any users).

Comment: There are application permissions (roles) and delegated permissions (scopes). You can get a list of all the roles and scopes by checking the serviceprincipal object for Graph in your tenant (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal).

Comment: Thanks @bluuf, when I execute the cmdlet you've suggested, I get the result ObjectId, AppId and DisplayName column only. Nothing showing about permission?

Comment: Powershell 101: with a lot of cmdlets only default properties show up by default in the console. Use format-list * to show all properties (or just it in a variable). The data is there (for the application I'm developing now I actually have to read and interact with this data)